# How to get the size of a partition in Cosmos DB collection?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am really surprised that I could not find this information.

I have seen a comment (without details) that there is a REST API to get this information.
I will try to find this information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use azure cli to get the size of a mongo collection like this.

```
az cosmosdb mongodb collection show -g myRG -a mycosmosaccount -d mydatabase -n mycollection
```

I also think you can get this via REST API on Management Plane. API sample for that is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db-resource-provider/2021-04-01-preview/mongo-db-resources/get-mongo-db-collection)

Comment: I have tried this command and it only shows collection metadata. I have found a way to get the required information -  go to Metrics(classic)  and then to Storage.

Comment: Yes, that works as well. Glad you found a solution.